# Agreement in comparative clause

Tags: comparative-constructions

> Those men actually run faster than **have/has** been expected.

Someone argued that the verb should agree with "those men", thus taking the plural form. But I think the understood subject of have/has isn't really "those men". It is what has been expected. So the correct verb form has to be "has". What do you think? Thank you.

Comment: The comparative clause is, as usual, reduced. In full it would be than _those men has/have been expected to run_. If the comparative clause is regarded as passive, then the grammatical subject is the plural "those men". Now consider using a pronoun instead of "those men" : _Those men actually run faster than they **have** / *has been been expected to run_. In that case, only plural "have" is possible.

Comment: @BillJ  I found this sentence from a previous thread: The crowds were larger than was expected (by someone).
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216201/than-need-be-vs-than-they-need-to-be/216208#216208
 Could you please explain why the verb "was" is in singular？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Those men actually run faster than have/has been expected

The correct usage would be "have been expected" since the subject is plural. However, it is easier to say "Those men actually run faster than expected". That, to me, sounds more natural.

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm confused. I found this sentence from a previous thread: The crowds were larger than was expected (by someone).
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216201/than-need-be-vs-than-they-need-to-be/216208#216208
 Could you please explain why the verb "was" is in singular